# Asp.Net Core [Bind] ,how to use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class TestBind
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("hhh")]
public async Task<JsonResult> HHH([Bind("A,B,C")] TestBind test)
{

}
```

What's the difference between `[Bind("A,B,C")]` and `[Bind("A,B,C,D,E,F,G")]`?

I have tested it many times and found no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Bind]` attribute can be applied to a class or a method parameter.Tells the model binder to only populate properties with names specified.

So in `[Bind("A,B,C")]` only the A, B and C properties will be populated. All others will be ignored.

The `[Bind]` attribute can be used to protect against overposting in *create* scenarios. It doesn't work well in edit scenarios because excluded properties are set to null or a default value instead of being left unchanged. For defense against overposting, view models are recommended rather than the `[Bind]` attribute.

See here for more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attributes-for-complex-type-targets

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between [Bind("A,B,C")] and
>   [Bind("A,B,C,D,E,F,G")]?

The former tells the model binder to include only the properties of `TestBind` named `A`, `B` and `C`. The latter tells the model binder to include those same properties plus `D`, `E`, `F` and `G`.

Are you testing by posting data for all properties of your model? You should notice that the values you post for the excluded properties are not bound.